# 404 error while loading js files

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am using webapp2 to build a webapp with angularjs. This is the directory structure.

```
|--test-app
   |--lib
   |--static
     |--js
       |--app.js
       |--controller.js
     |--lib
       |--angular
       |--angualr-bootstrap
     |--index.html
   |--app.yaml
   |--mainapp.py
```

But when I try to load the js files in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="testApp">
   <head>
     <script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/controller.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div ng-controller="MainController">
       IN MAIN
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get these errors:

1. `GET http://localhost:8080/static/js/app.js` (404 - file not found)
2. `GET http://localhost:8080/static/js/controller.js`  (404 - file not found)

I cannot figure out why I am getting these errors.

Here is code for `app.yaml`

```
application: test-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: mainapp.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Here is code for `mainapp.py`

```
    class Start(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
            self.response.write(open('static/index.html').read())

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', Start),
    ], debug=True)
```

Comment: I guess static is not needed it can be simply src="js/controller.js" and "js/app.js"

Comment: no this too won't work .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must explicitly declare the location of your static content in `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: mainapp.app
```

See [docs](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html) for details:

> Unlike a traditional web hosting environment, Google App Engine does not serve files directly out of your application’s source directory unless configured to do so.

URL handler path patterns are tested in the order they appear in `app.yaml`, from top to bottom. In this case, the `/static` pattern will match before the `/.*` pattern will for the appropriate paths.

Comment: No , this didn't solve the problem . I am still getting 404 file not found.

Comment: Did you put it _before_ your `- url: /.*` handler? The order is important.

Comment: Yes, I did so , but didn't work . Do I have to make any changes in mainapp.py ?

Answer (score 2):

I moved the index.html out of the static folder and then declared explicitly the static url, as said by @Selcuk. And it works nows.

Comment: you could have that as a comment on his answer.. as this is not really an answer :)